# Does encrypting core database using NSFileProtectionComplete protects data even during sync to iTunes as well?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, sqlite

Does encrypting core data using NSFileProtectionComplete protects it from syncing the database to iTunes?

Answer (score 0):

No. The NSFileProtectionComplete only encrypts the core data files if the user has passcodes on their device. It does not change the backup behaviors of the device.

Controlling backup behaviors varies by iOS version http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011342

In 5.1 and later you can use

```
assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
if(!success){
    NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
}
```